# Как запретить повторное нажатие кнопки в течение например 3 секунд

Tags: javascript

(То есть нажал на кнопку функция сработала, но еще раз на нее можно было нажать через 3 секунды)

````
function again() {
    if(timer.innerHTML == 0) {
        console.log('if');
        cell.forEach((item) => {
            item.style.background = 'orange';
            item.innerHTML = '';
            arr = [ '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '' ];
            sec = 20;
            setTimeout(myGreeting, 20000)
            
          })
    }    else {
        console.log('else');```
    }
}
````

Answer (score 3):

```js
let button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  button.disabled = true;
  setTimeout(() => button.disabled = false, 3000);
});
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```