# Как сделать ограничение на количество кликов в секунду js

Tags: javascript

Как можно реализовать ограниченное количество кликов в секунду по кнопке с помощью js.

Если вот такой вот код - [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/j0cqL5eg/)

Нужно сделать так чтобы на кнопку с id="big-btn" можно было нажать не больше 15 раз в 1 секунду. Если пользователь нажимает более 15 раз то должно срабатывать действие, например появляться всплывающие окно.

```
var clicks = 0;

function insertText(clicks) {
  document.getElementById('clicks-count').innerText = clicks;
}

const onClick = () => {
    clicks += 1;
    insertText(clicks);
}

document.getElementById('big-btn').addEventListener('click', onClick)
```

```
<div class="n1">
  <button id="big-btn">Клик</button>
  <div id="clicks-count">0</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Речь точно о кликах мышкой, не о нажатиях клавиши? Не могу представить себе человека, кликающего 15 раз в секунду. :)
В любом случае, можно использовать такую конструкцию. Она будет обрабатывать клики раз в 100мс, все остальные клики игнорируются.

```js
var clicks = 0;

function delay(f) {

  let isCooldown = false;

  return function() {
    if (isCooldown) return;

    f.apply(this, arguments);

    isCooldown = true;

    setTimeout(() => isCooldown = false, 100);
  };

}

function insertText(clicks) {
  document.getElementById('clicks-count').innerText = clicks;
}

const onClick = () => {
    console.log('click!');
    clicks += 1;
    insertText(clicks);
}

document.getElementById('big-btn').addEventListener('click', delay(onClick))
```

```html
<div class="n1">
  <button id="big-btn">Клик</button>
  <div id="clicks-count">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Только что увидел простое решение в соседнем вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453121/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-3-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4

Comment: Тут как раз речь идет не о человеке, а о программах автокликера. Просто в большинство программах можно выставить нажатия 1 раз в 10мс, что дает пользователю преимущества. 

Ваше решение помогло, спасибо